# What are my Office 365 users doing that's using Exchange EWS?

Tags: exchange, microsoft-office-365

I understand why they are using or not using EAS/POP3/IMAP/MAPI/OWA, but I'm not sure what they are doing that is using EWS. I can see quite a few users connecting via EWS some days.

Generally we use Outlook 2010/2013, EAS on iPhones etc, Blackberry with BES, OWA and Lync.

Any ideas what's using EWS?

My PowerShell command:

```
get-connectionbyclienttypedetailreport -StartDate 08/01/13 -enddate 08/31/13 | where "clienttype"-eq "ews"  | sort-object username
```

Answer (score 1):

The BES server will use Exchange Web Services (EWS), using impersonation to manage Blackberry calendars.

[BES Office 365 PDF](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/admin/deliverables/49530/721-08633-123_BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server_for_Microsoft_Office_365_preinstallation_tasks_JA_v1.pdf)

> By default, the BlackBerry Enterprise Server uses Microsoft Exchange
>   Web Services to manage calendars on BlackBerry devices.

So, assuming the users you are referring to are indeed BB users, that would make sense.

Comment: I guess that would explain why it's not all BB users. Only those who have made updates to their calendar from their BB device, I assume. Thanks.

Comment: Just checking. I see some users who don't have Blackberry devices in the EWS list too!

Comment: Who are the users in the PS results and what are they using to access Exchange online?  Office for Mac uses EWS as well.

Comment: Just a mixture of users. Yeah, I know about Office for Mac - but we don't have any of those either. It's odd. it's not causing me a problem - I'm just curious to know what is happening. Could it be anything to do with SharePoint Online? Lync?

Comment: A Sharepoint site that uses an Exchange calendar probably uses EWS, but I haven't bothered to look.  Lync uses it for presence info from the Exchange calendar of the user.  So it's probably a combo of these things showing up in your PS results.  I haven't watched this yet, but plan on doing so.  It may even point out in detail your answer: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Open-Specifications-Plugfests/Redmond-Interoperability-Protocols-Plugfest-2013/Exchange-Office-365-Dedicated

Comment: I don't think we have any calendars being used on SharePoint, so the Lync presence status seems more likely. But then again, I am connected to Lync all day every day and I don't show as one of the users using EWS!

Comment: I show as accessing via EWS on just 5 separate days in August 2013. I was in the office pretty much every working day.

Comment: Sorry man, I don't know how to determine exactly what EWS is doing per client and why.  The best I can say is that `Get-ConnectionByClientTypeDetailReport` shows who accessed it but not necessarily why.  I hope you find the full answer...and share it here for others (including myself) to learn from.

Comment: I will certainly update if I find out. I may well ask Microsoft or our Office 365 Partner. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: I disabled EWS for myself and had Lync connection issues off and on. So I'm thinking Lync probably uses EWS.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook clients since Office 2007 use EWS for many things.  Some common tasks for which EWS is used are:
Delegates
Free/Busy
Out-of-Office

I suspect that as outlook progresses in updates and versions, it will use EWS more and more so as to lessen the footprint over time of using MAPI/HTTP and RPC/HTTP.

For example, the newer O365 Groups feature i'm sure is facilitated by some EWS calls as well.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to really get actionable information is to trawl IIS logs for connections to an on-premises Exchange server.  [Info on searching IIS logs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/caseys/archive/2012/01/23/troubleshooting-ews-requests-using-iis-logs-with-logparser.aspx).  Unfortunately you get no such access in O365.

I can tell you that Lync definitely uses EWS, for things like calendar lookup and Presence updates.

I have yet to find a definitive list of Microsoft services that use EWS.  I have recently reached out to some of the Microsoft Garage teams and they gave me the UserAgent ID for some apps.  [My own notes on the matter.](http://blaughwtech.blogspot.com/2015/07/block-microsoft-send-app-in-ews-policy.html)

> Microsoft Garage **Send** app: "MicrosoftSend/*"
>
> Microsoft Garage **Tossup** app: "OutlookApps Tossup/Prod"